# Linux и Windows интернет один, скорость скачивания разная!

Tags: windows-7, linux

Очень интересует вопрос, как сделать такую же скорость на w7. При использовании linux скорость скачивания была от 300кб/с до 500, а на w7 110кб/с.

Comment: а вы скачивали точно из одного и того же ресурса?

Comment: Попробуйте **Mac** может быть ещё быстрее будет xD  
Забавляет вопрос)

Comment: всегда с одного http://rutracker.org. поэтому и задался таким вопросом.

Comment: Настораживает "скорость была". Т.е. после w7 вы пробовали скачивать под linux? Если нет, то возможно проблема внешняя и падение скорости просто совпало по времени.

Comment: Ладно, поставим вопрос так. На винде я пользуюсь уторент.На торренте у меня максимальная скорость 110 кб/с. Не больше даже если 5 торрентов то скорость делится но максимальное это 110. На линуксе уторнет не идет, но есть стандартная, не помню названия что с bit... Программа совершенна проста в использовании, там почти не функций и настроек. Но скорость 500кб/с делилась на n-торрентов. Дело в том что у меня 3g-modem, то есть скорость на нем не может меняться, но даже если может то, это жуткое стечение обстоятельств что месяц пользования linux модем работал в 5 раз быстрее.))

Comment: 3g модем ВООБЩЕ не показатель.. повернул ноут на 20 см - качество соединения упало.... От климатических и сезонных условий тоже зависит. От оператора и т.п.))

Comment: Тут речь идет не о часе, а о месяце

Comment: есть конечно призрачный % что OS влияет на скорость работы с инетом но вероятность этого крайне ничтожна. может быть linux лучше работает с 3g модемом за счет этого скорость выше. возможно сам linux клиент для p2p протокола работает лучше. всякое может быть. к тому же для windows есть легенда про то что QoS отжирает 20% канала (хотя это лишь легенда). лучше всего конечно же как порекомендовали вам использовать для проверки тесты скорости чем какие-то наблюдения. тесты могут ошибатся но не в 5 раз.

Comment: А какой умник заминусовал **реально интересный** вопрос ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вопрос не такой уж и плохой. С одной стороны [[@nikita_sergeevich](/users/5925/nikita_sergeevich)](/users/5925/nikita_sergeevich) и [[@uzumaxy](/users/1015/uzumaxy)](/users/1015/uzumaxy) правы, но с другой, позволю себе заметить, что [[@jmu](/users/1810/jmu)](/users/1810/jmu) верно в комментариях так же упомянул о различиях в p2p клиентах. Например (и только например), в Windows uTorrent может полагаться исключительно на ресурсы, выделяемые ему операционной системой, которая в свою очередь может пытаться безуспешно оптимизировать канал посредством изменения размера окна TCP, весьма затратная операция на нестабильных каналах связи.

В свою же очередь клиент для Linux может это делать самостоятельно (или же ОС может работать иначе). А так как задержка на 3G - весьма весомый аргумент, то и ошибки приемо-передачи, подстройки окна, могут сильно влиять на скорость.

Более того, подстройка размера отправляемой дейтаграммы может играть роль, для 1500 байт (стандарт Ethernet) задержка превышает допустимую (а как известно и как писал я выше, Windows будет пытаться слать больше, и реже запрашивать подтверждение, чтобы достичь максимальной пропускной способности канала), а для уменьшенной дейтаграммы, например, в 500 байт, все нормально, передача идет, пусть не на максимально возможной скорости, но близкой к ней, пусть не постоянной скорости в 500, а 300~500, но передача идет.

Попробуйте, посмотреть с помощью `wireshark`, что происходит с TCP пакетами, сколько раз данные перезапрашиваются, сколько раз изменяется размер окна TCP и т.п. в данных ОС. Что-то мне подсказывает, что в Linux картина будет несколько отличаться. Чтобы на него ответить точнее, придется побольше узнать о том, что реально происходит во время передачи.

---

**UPD**

Что мы у вас видим:

1. Дейтафрейм номер 277 (смотрите столбец `№`), отправляем, говорим, что все приняли верно
2. После него мы получаем 304й, в котором `Sequence number` сравнивается с `Acknowledge number` из (1) (если все хорошо, они должны быть равны), а здесь они не равны, в итоге у нас дейтафрейм передан не верно (утерян), и его необходимо запросить снова. Что мы, собственно и делаем в следующем, №305 (Dup-ACK).
3. А 306м мы получаем нашу пропажу, правда несколько очень маленьким окном (254, т.е. всего без подтверждения мы можем передавать очень и очень мало байт), помеченный как `Out-of-order`.
4. Подтверждаем принятие в 307 и повторяем с начала.

В идеальном случае, у вас должна идти передача, состоящая из нескольких дейтафреймов (например, как в 3155-3156), и одно подтверждение (3157). Подтверждение отправляется в двух случаях, если количество отправленных байт = размеру окна или стоит флаг PSH (Push - например, это значит, что в буфере на передающей стороне закончились данные и нужно их снова подготовить).

Поэтому стоит поковыряться в настройках, попытаться оптимизировать канал для 3G и его задержек и скоростей. Стоит копать в сторону `Receive window size` ([здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736.aspx)). А еще загляните [сюда](http://www.speedguide.net/articles/the-tcp-window-latency-and-the-bandwidth-delay-2678). Думаю, что есть программки, которые помогут вам это сделать автоматически, только задайте "честную" скорость не преувеличивая.

Попробовать поиграться с ключами реестра:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interface\<interface>
>
> найти ТсрWindowSize и задать значение
> от 0 до 0x3FFFFFFF

Или попробовать совсем отключить масштабирование окна (хотя не самая удачная мысль, но попробовать можно), действует более глобально, чем предыдущий параметр, будьте осторожны

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
>
> Tcp1323Opts - установить в 0

Comment: Я скачал wireshark. Не могли бы подсказать что делать то с ним?

Comment: Запускаете, выбираете интерфейс, к которому подключен ваш модем (слева под меню самая первая кнопка), затем в поле `Filter:` пишите `tcp` и нажимаете `Enter` или кнопку `Apply`. Торрент уже считаю запущенным.

И наблюдаете за строками, которые имеют необычный цвет (отличный от остальных, например, `темно-бордовый - Maroon`), и читаете, что пишется для этих дейтаграмм. Полагаю, что с "необычным" цветом в Windows должно быть больше.

Можете немного пособирать дейтаграммы, затем остановить сбор (одна из первых кнопок) и сохранить лог, выложить его куда-то и дать ссылку здесь.

Comment: Была у нас в чем-то похожая ситуация (необъяснимостью ?), но для гигабитной сетки. Простая программа с TCP сокетами на Си много шлет, потом много получает в ответ (другая тоже своя на Си). Так и не разобрались, почему на Linux работает намного быстрее. 

Самое интересное, что на Windows ситуация вообще была ассиметричная, кто начал, тот передает быстрее.

На 100Мбит все работало одинаково.

Comment: дело в том что я не могу linux поставить себе, он снесет всю инфу на дисках. В w7 я сделал лог. Но без показателей с linux нельзя ничего сравнить. Чувствую придется о linux думать, как о конфетах в антресолях...И вкусные и классные, но недоступные)))

Мне совершенно не понравилась реализация wine (помню программа была, эмулятор сеги, так он и то ровнее показывал все), а так как мне нужно очень много программ с w7, да и в linuxe я чувствовал себя ребенком, который даже настройки найти не мог, пришлось вновь положить конфеты в антресоль.

Comment: Вот лог w7 если нужно http://файлообменник.рф/ac0fth1ibjuc.html

Comment: Да, вот именно так и работает винда:) У вас с самого начала все дейтаграммы сыпятся в (черным выделены дейтаграммы с красными буквами):

> DUP ACK
>
> Previous segment lost
>
> TCP Retransmission
>
> и др.

И вот из-за этого, винда выдает 100кбит, при возможных 500, а может быть и меньше. У меня похожая проблема была с оперой, которая не хотела грузить ВКонтакте, проблему так и не решил, времени не было полностью разобраться.

Смотрите UPD.

Answer (score 1):

Как полоса пропускания зависит от операционки?! >__<
Теоремы Шеннона-Хартли на вас нету...
Юзай [тест скорости](http://2ip.ru/speed/). А не разные торренты с разным кол-ом сидов и пиров!

P.S. как вариант отключай автообнавление *мелкомягкого софта*, которое забивает канал...

Answer (score 1):

> всегда с одного http://rutracker.org.
> поэтому и задался таким вопросом.

rutracker.org - торрент трекер. Скорость скачивания торрентов может зависеть не только от "размера" канала, но и от раздающих этот торрент. Видимо когда вы работали под Линуксом, то отдача у раздающих была побольше, чем в в случае загрузки из-под Windows. Отсюда и вся магия с изменением скорости. 
Оценить реальную скорость интренет-соединение можно разными способами и торренты - не лучший из них. Используйте сайты типа 2ip.ru для оценки среднего быстродействия сети.

Возможны и другие причины разной скорости на 2-х осях, но они маловероятны.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отключить Файрвол и антивирус.

Запретите авто-обновление.